# Jupyter Notebook: %%time magic loses global variables

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Variables declared inside a `%% time` cell in jupyter do not show up in subsequent cells.

```
In [1]: %%time
        a = 2

In [2]: print(a)

NameError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bca0e2660b9f> in <module>
----> 1 print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Is this a bug or by design? I don't remember facing this issue before.

I am using Python 3.7.3 with Jupyter 4.4.0 and IPython 7.4.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I usually use `%%timeit`, which runs the expression many times.  It's normal that timing doesn't 'bleed' into the global namespace.

Comment: @hpaulj That's not how jupyter magic works - it only runs the cell once and times the execution. This appears to be a bug in IPython 7.4. Found the bug report here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For folks running into this issue in the future, this is a bug in Ipython 7.4. The bug report is here - https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11659

It got fixed in Ipython 7.5.

Updating ipython to 7.5 using `conda update ipython` solved the issue.